# ValueError installing a python/django project

Tags: python, django

I am installing a python project from github (https://github.com/sunlightlabs/publicmarkup) and I get this error message :

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 283, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 273, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 214, in handle_uncaught_exception
    if resolver.urlconf_module is None:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 274, in _get_urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "/home/mbenchoufi/git/publicmarkup/../publicmarkup/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    add_to_builtins('mediasync/templatetags/media')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1016, in add_to_builtins
    builtins.append(import_library(module))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 951, in import_library
    app_path, taglib = taglib_module.rsplit('.',1)

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I am a newbie to python, what does this error message means ?

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback. `taglib_module` doesn't contain a `.` period character so there is nothing to split, but why this is the case depends on the rest of the code path.

Comment: Which python project? What do you mean by "installing"? (As in, what command you're executing?)

Comment: Otherwise, what the error means at a basic level is that the expression `taglib_module.rsplit('.',1)` returned an iterable with only one element.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have just edited the traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add_to_builtins` call in `publicmarkup/urls.py` is incorrect, it should *probably* be:

```
add_to_builtins('mediasync.templatetags.media')
```

Python packages are dot-delimited and the author used a path instead.

Later on, the Django framework tries to load the module, and splitting off the last name after the last dot fails as there are no dots in the original call.

It looks like the project you are trying to load is fundamentally broken. It probably will have other errors as well.